# "expression must have class type" error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, syntax-error

I got "expression must have class type" error while defining a method in a C++ `struct`. I do not know why.

The code:

```cpp
struct qqueue {

    int ar[20000];
    int rear = 0;

    void add_end(int c) {
        ar[rear++] = c;
        
    }

    void add_front( int c) {
        if (rear < ar.sz - 1) {               // expression must have class type
            for (int i = rear; i > 0; i--)
                ar[i] = ar[i - 1];
            ar[0] = c;
            rear++;
        }
        else
            cout << " is Full";
    }
};
```

Comment: How can we possible help you with errors in code if we don't see the code itself. So please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Remember to put a comment on the line where you get the error. Also please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Arrays are not C++ objects, and doesn't have member variables of functions. If you want an array object with a `size` member use either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (for fixed-size arrays where the size is known at compile-time) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for "dynamic arrays" that can be added to at run-time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that `ar.sz` is supposed to mean. This is the syntax to access a member of a class, and thus invalid for a raw array. If you think it means something like the size of an array, no, it doesn't, and I have no idea were you learned that wrong syntax.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I got it.sorry I forgot to include it in code, but I use this macro: #define sz size()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar.sz
```

does not work. `ar` is of type int[], which doesn't have any members. since you know the size at compile time, you may want to write 20000.

Since you are using cpp, I'd suggest using `std::vector` or `std::array`